# How can I position the second modal on top of the first modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal stacked on top of another modal. How can I position the second modal on top of the first modal? See jsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/imonareng/rhhyu6h2/25/).

The problem I am currently having is positioning the second modal exactly on top of the first modal. The first modal seem to ignore the space occupied by the scroll bar, however the second modal doesn't and as a result the second modal appeared to have shifted to the right and smaller than the first modal (just my assumption).

I tried adding the following but doesn't work:

```
.modal-content {
    margin: auto !important; 
}
```

Comment: Looks like your 2 levels of popups are working. It always seems like you are doing something wrong if you are having to place a popup on top of another popup. Might be worth looking at your UX and get it down to just the one level of popups. Also how does this work on mobile.

Comment: Sorry my bad, the problem seem occur when you have overflows in the y-direction. Make the display section shorter and you will see what I talking about.

Answer (score 1):

if you set modal-content height to 368px this will work, as this is the size of the first popup modal.

```
.modal-content {
  min-height: 368px;
}
```

[See updated jsfiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/rhhyu6h2/26/)

```js
// bootstrap 3.3.6
// jquery 2.2.1
// fontawesome 4.5.0

  /* 
   MODAL STACKING  
  */
  // Backdrop z-index fix 
  $(document).on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
   var zIndex = 1040 + (10 * $('.modal:visible').length);
   $(this).css('z-index', zIndex);
   setTimeout(function() {
    $('.modal-backdrop').not('.modal-stack').css('z-index', zIndex - 1).addClass('modal-stack');
   }, 0);
  });
  // Scrollbar fix
  $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
   $('.modal:visible').length && $(document.body).addClass('modal-open');
  });
```

```css
.modal-content {
    margin: auto !important; 
    min-height: 368px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="services" class="padding-bottom">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                            <h1 class="section-heading turquoise">At Your Service</h1>
                            <hr class="underlined_orange">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <!-- Thumbnail -->
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 text-center">
                            <a href="#" title="More about Branding &amp; Marketing" target="_self" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#marketing">
                                <div class="service-box">
                                    <i class="fa fa-5x fa-globe turquoise sr-icons" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <h2 class="orange">Service 1</h2>
                                    <p>About Service 1</p><br>
                                    <p class="turquoise automaticaBRK"><br><span class="btn btn-default sketchFlowPrint">Open Modal</span><br></p>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        
                        <!-- Branding & Digital Marketing Modal -->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="marketing" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="marketing-xLabel">
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><i class="fa fa-times orange" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                        <h1 class="modal-title" id="marketing-xLabel">Service</h1>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body text-center">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6 service-box">
                                                <i class="fa fa-5x turquoise fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                    <br><br>
                                                    <h2>Less info</h2>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default automaticaBRK" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#brandingOptions">See Even More about this service</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <!-- Modal -->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="brandingOptions" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="brandingOptions-xLabel">
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><i class="fa fa-times orange" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                        <h1 class="modal-title" id="brandingOptions-xLabel">More about Service</h1>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body text-center">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                             <div class="housePlanPackage">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-5x turquoise fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                    <br><br>
                                                    <h2>Too much info</h2>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
```

Comment: I realized that the problem is on a smaller screens (where the height is smaller than the modal and the scrollbar is showing). If you reduce the height of the screen you are viewing the jsFiddle, you will see the problem. If you increase the height, the problem goes away!

Comment: @InnocentMonareng check it with min-height

Comment: I don't think we are on the same page. The problem I am having is in the x-axis. The moment the screen is smaller (shorter) than the modal, the width of the second modal becomes relatively smaller compared to the first modal. Meaning you can see fraction of the first modal on the left side of the screen behind the second modal. However on the right side of the screen the modals are aligned properly. The fraction of the first modal appearing on the left it is about the same size as the scroll bar on the right... Hence I made the assumptions stated above.